Best practices для хранения конфигурации микросервисов со Spring Cloud
В проекте есть порядка 10 микросервисов, доступ к которым организован через Spring Cloud + key cloak.
Инфраструктура развернута в k8s.
Я читаю, что есть разные подходы для хранения файлов конфигурации app-test.yaml , app-prod.yaml

Хранить app.yaml во внутреннем репозитории и каждый сервис сам запрашивает конфиги через spring cloud.
Подключить HashiCorp Vault и хранить ключи в нем.
хранить в k8s через argo cd

система не большая, особой нагрузки нет. Какой подход для хранения конфигов и ключей считается сейчас лучшим.
